# ASP.NET MVC Create controller action not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have created a basic MVC solution using the entity framework. But when I put dummy data in the create form and click create, nothing happens. No new entries are made into the DB and the page does not return to the controller index. Most code is scaffolded by Visual Studio so I'm not sure what is wrong.

The controller should handle a create action, taking data from the form on the create page, put it in the right database and return to the index of the controller. Instead, the page remains on the create form with my dummy data still in the fields. No entryis ever inputted in the database.

**My create view:
**

```
@model DCServer.Models.Driver

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Driver</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="scooberId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="scooberId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="scooberId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="driverName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="driverName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="driverName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="driverScore" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="driverScore" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="driverScore" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="employedTime" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="employedTime" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="employedTime" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="amtApproaches" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="amtApproaches" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="amtApproaches" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="amtEvaluated" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="amtEvaluated" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="amtEvaluated" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="lastEvaluated" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="lastEvaluated" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="lastEvaluated" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**My model:
**

```
using MessagePack;
using System;

namespace DCServer.Models
{
    public class Driver
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int scooberId { get; set; }
        public string driverName { get; set; }
        public string driverScore { get; set; }
        public float employedTime { get; set; }
        public string amtApproaches { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Approach> Approaches { get; set; }
        public int amtEvaluated { get; set; }
        public float lastEvaluated { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Evaluation> Evaluations { get; set; }
        public Driver()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**My controller
**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using DCServer.Data;
using DCServer.Models;

namespace DCServer.Controllers
{
    public class DriversController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public DriversController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Drivers
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
              return View(await _context.Driver.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Drivers/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Driver == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var driver = await _context.Driver
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (driver == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(driver);
        }

        // GET: Drivers/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Drivers/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,scooberId,driverName,driverScore,employedTime,amtApproaches,amtEvaluated,lastEvaluated")] Driver driver)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _context.Add(driver);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }


            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }
            return View(driver);
        }

        // GET: Drivers/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Driver == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var driver = await _context.Driver.FindAsync(id);
            if (driver == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(driver);
        }

        // POST: Drivers/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,scooberId,driverName,driverScore,employedTime,amtApproaches,amtEvaluated,lastEvaluated")] Driver driver)
        {
            if (id != driver.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(driver);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!DriverExists(driver.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(driver);
        }

        // GET: Drivers/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Driver == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var driver = await _context.Driver
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (driver == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(driver);
        }

        // POST: Drivers/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Driver == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Driver'  is null.");
            }
            var driver = await _context.Driver.FindAsync(id);
            if (driver != null)
            {
                _context.Driver.Remove(driver);
            }
            
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool DriverExists(int id)
        {
          return _context.Driver.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "nothing happens"?  Does the page not even reload?  In your browser's debugging tools, are no new network requests made at all?  Are there any errors in the browser's development console?  If you place a debugging breakpoint in all of the server-side action methods, none of them are invoked?

Comment: Sorry should have been more elaborate! The page does seem to reload, I can see a POST request being made after filling out the form and clicking the "create" button from the debugging tools. No errors in the browser console. I tried a few breakpoints, they still get triggered inside the create POST method. They do not get triggered inside the if (ModelState.IsValid) statement.

Comment: So you have observed during debugging that `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`?  What else does `ModelState` tell you then?  What is invalid about it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as I'm fairly new to ASP.NET but from some research it seems that this means it was not possible to bind incoming values to the model causing ModelState to be invalid. There are no exceptions thrown so I'm not sure what causes the invalidation.

Comment: When debugging, observe the properties on [the `ModelState` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.modelstate).  If it's not valid, it will (should) contain error messages indicating the validation problem.  Currently your code is just ignoring those messages and returning control to the page, telling the user (you) nothing.

Comment: Took some time to debug and the ModelState object contains 2 errors. It appears that the two ICollection interfaces in the model are returning invalid as they are empty. This makes sense as ModelState expects values for all properties as specified in the ViewModel. Will have to figure out how to ignore these properties which is off-topic. This clarified the main problem though so thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Even if you set `method="post"` also doesn't work? Could you please check?

Comment: Could you please share `Approach` and `Evaluation` details, I have tested along wtih your code snippet and its hitting the controller and `model state` is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It appears that the two ICollection interfaces in the model are
> returning invalid as they are empty.

I'm afraid you may use `.NET 6`/`.NET 7`. From `.NET 6` the **non-nullable property must be required**, otherwise the ModelState will be invalid.

To achieve your requirement, **the first way** is you can remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file(double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File).

**The second way**, you can initialize the model like below:

```
public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //other properties...
    public virtual ICollection<Approach> Approaches { get; set; } = new List<Approach>();
    public int amtEvaluated { get; set; }
    public float lastEvaluated { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Evaluation> Evaluations { get; set; } = new List<Evaluation>();
    public Driver()
    {

    }
}
```

**The third way**, you can add `?` to allow nullable:

```
public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //other properties.....
    public virtual ICollection<Approach>? Approaches { get; set; } 
    public int amtEvaluated { get; set; }
    public float lastEvaluated { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Evaluation>? Evaluations { get; set; } 
    public Driver()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks alot for your help. I was indeed using .NET 6. Allowing the two navigation properties to be nullable by adding "?" solved the problem of ModelState being invalid.